# Looking for a moderately priced home surveillance setup

Tags: webcam, product-rec, home-surveillance

I've got a need for a comprehensive home surveillance solution that meets the following criteria

- no monthly charges
- support for multiple cameras (preferably over ethernet or wifi)
- motion detection
- sensors triggered by doors/windows opening, water, or smoke
- alerting via email and SMS
- remote access portal

I know I'm asking for the world here.. but i just can't seem to find a solution that has all these features.  I'm thinking i might have to cobble one together myself and script together all the logic needed to make everything work.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, i've done some homework.  Decided to go with an Open Source dot.net solution called [iSpy](http://ispy.developerinabox.com/).  It supports several inputs, has motion detection algorithms, and I can modify the source code to add support for additional features i want.

Answer (score 2):

I suggested InGrid here:

https://superuser.com/questions/2929/can-you-suggest-a-great-home-security-setup-anti-burglars-e-t-c

No personal experience with it yet.

Answer (score 1):

**Super User Archive:**

- [Can you suggest a great home security setup (anti burglars e.t.c.)](https://superuser.com/questions/2929/can-you-suggest-a-great-home-security-setup-anti-burglars-e-t-c)