# Recommendations for a surveillance camera kit that I can remotely access

Tags: camera, home-surveillance, network-camera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for a moderately priced home surveillance setup](https://superuser.com/questions/3054/looking-for-a-moderately-priced-home-surveillance-setup)

Can anyone recommend a decent surveillance camera kit, nothing fancy, that will allow me to access it from any computer (whether it's through a webpage or client program I need to install)?

I just saw a deal on Newegg for [this surveillance camera kit](http://www.newegg.com/product/product.aspx?nm_mc=AFC-TechBargains&cm_mmc=AFC-TechBargains-_-NA-_-NA-_-NA&Item=N82E16881109038) and it got me to thinking about installing a setup in my house.

Comment: Which of these dupes would better suit to close as? http://superuser.com/questions/79050/security-webcam http://superuser.com/questions/3054/moderately-priced-home-surveillance http://superuser.com/questions/2929/suggest-a-home-security-setup - Though that wiki one is filled with a moat.

Comment: That one! Though I could edit in the others...

Comment: @dr dork the "possible duplicate" links have their purpose. (Also note that the two-letter "dr" *might* interfere with notifications of comments to questions or answers that are not yours -- see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/)